# Past of verbs such as "long" and "wing"

Tags: phonetics

Assuming their past is regular, are they pronounced as /wɪŋd/ and /lɑːŋd/ or does a [gd] surface at the end?

Comment: Those accents which have /g/ in the base form have it in the past. Those which don't, don't. (This belongs on ELL, not on Linguistics).

Comment: True. However, _long_ (v) does have one interesting morphological feature. The comparative _-er_ suffix added to _long_ (adj) meaning 'more long' makes /lɔŋ/ into /lɔŋɡər/ (American vowels) with a /ɡ/. But the agentive _-er_ suffix added to _long_ (v), meaning 'one who longs', adds no /g/. One who longs is a _longer_ (same spelling), but there's no /g/ -- it's pronounced /lɔŋər/.

Comment: @jlawler. An interesting observation. I wonder if there is some general rule about this.

Comment: I find [gd] possible, in a slow, emphatic pronunciation.  After all, whether you get the intrusive [g] is just a matter of timing the movement of the velum and the back of the tongue.

Comment: @fdb: I don't think so. _Strong_ follows _long_, but _wrong_ doesn't. I can't think of any other adjectives ending in /ŋ/.

Comment: the two *long* lexems are expected to reconstruct two roots with different velars (citation needed). I would be surprised if those are not ultimately connected, anyhow. For various reasons I hypothesise "to long" actually compares to *lego* or *ligo*, in a sense "to collect, select, choose, wish", the *n* being an innovation; cp similarly Ger *stark* "strong"; Ger *winken* "to wave", *Woge* "wave, wake". This might have implications for "finger" /-ger/, cp e.g. *figure*, *digit*, Ger *Fuchtel*, fig. "Hand". I'm really only posting because *Fuchtel* is a funny word, or should I say *funky*?